# C program Moving documents between collection in Mongodb

Tags: c, mongodb

I am new to C program, and currently writing a C program to retrieve data from Mongodb and moving this data from one collection to other collection.

Here is my code to retrieve data:

```
bson query[1];
bson_init(query);
bson_append_start_object(query,"time");
bson_append_string(query, "$gt", starttime);
bson_append_string(query, "$lte", endtime);
bson_append_finish_object(query);
bson_finish(query);

mongo_cursor cursor[1];
mongo_cursor_init( cursor, conn, "dbA.collectionA");
mongo_cursor_set_query( cursor, query);

while( mongo_cursor_next(cursor) == MONGO_OK){
//read the data and display it
...

//here I want to move the documents from collectionA to collectionB
}
```

I could successfully show the data, however, I dont know how to move this data to another collection after I display it, could anyone help or any tips??

Thank u very much !!

Comment: the code above will display the data retrieve from collectionA, and I could like to move this data which fulfill the condition to collectionB, then after, delete this record in collectionA!

Comment: What isn't documented here (http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html) that you need?